# Regex pattern for date time validation

Tags: regex

I'm using this regex pattern for date time validation:

```
$regexp = 
"/^([0][1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[0-1])\\/([0][1-9]|1[0-2])\\/(\d{4}) ([0-9]|1[0-2])\\:([0-5][0-9]) (am|pm)$/";
```

It isn't validating this [input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37770728/regex-pattern-for-date-time-validation#comment63010504_37770728) (but it should):

```
11/06/2016 06:28 pm
```

Where is the problem with it?

Comment: *What* problem? Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: A wild guess, since you don't give us that much to work on is that you get the error `( is not a valid modifier`, correct? That is because the char before that / is a modifier and it is not escaped. So on both / in the pattern make them \/ and see if that works.

Comment: For clarity: `$regexp = "/^([0][1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[0-1])\/([0][1-9]|1[0-2])\/(\d{4}) ([0-9]|1[0-2]):([0-5][0-9]) (am|pm)$/";`

Comment: still getting error.. unable to validate correct date and timme

Comment: So what does the error say? And what string are you trying to validate? We need to see the input

Comment: 11/06/2016 06:28 pm   this is the input

Comment: See my answer below

Comment: Please include key extra information (such as an example string) in the question — rather than in the comments.  I transferred the information for you this time, but please do it yourself next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a error at the hours. Your string is two digit hour but regex was one digit.

```
preg_match("/([0][1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[0-1])\/([0][1-9]|1[0-2])\/(\d{4}) (0[0-9]|1[0-2]):([0-5][0-9]) (am|pm)/", $time);
```

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/g0B

Comment: @harshagarwal odd.. can you post the string? I mean the full string, because your pattern says the strin can only have the time as value, nothing else. If you remove ^ at start and $ at end it can handle a string like: `I was driving from work at 11/06/2016 06:28 pm`, but with $ and ^ it can only match `11/06/2016 06:28 pm`

Comment: @harshagarwal can you please accept the answer? The V-shaped button next to my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
'^(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])\/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(19|20)\d{2} (0[0-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9] (am|pm)$'
```

It will validate dates between `01/01/1900` to `31/12/2099` (dd-mm-yyyy) with time in hh:mm format with am or pm.

Or use the below one to validate all years except `0000`:

```
'^(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])\/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/\d{4}(?<!0000) (0[0-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9] (am|pm)$'
```

Comment: Why did you put year first? His string has year last.

Comment: Oh! I didn't see his example string

Comment: Keep on cleaning... `Also, you are using \d{4} which will capture 4 digits but you need 2 digits in dd as in yyyy-mm-dd.` :-)

Comment: @Andreas i did it :D